# Django: Giving validation error feedback on a form after a post redirect get

Tags: django, post-redirect-get

I have a good bit of experience in non-Django web development, but I am struggling to find a good practice for handling what to do when the user enters invalid data in their form and I want to re-display the form with their submitted data and the form errors displayed as well.  I have a simple form with three fields and this is how I finally made it work.

```
def get(self, request) :
    # Check if we have been redirected...
    redirect_html = request.session.pop('form_error_html', False)
    if redirect_html : return HttpResponse(redirect_html)

    old_data = {'title': 'SakaiCar', 'mileage' : 42, 
        'purchase_date': '2018-08-14' }
    form = BasicForm(initial=old_data)
    ctx = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', ctx)

def post(self, request) :
    form = BasicForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid() :
        ctx = {'form' : form}
        html = render_to_string('form.html', ctx, request=request)
        request.session['form_error_html'] = html
        return redirect(request.path)

    # Do something with the valid data..
    return redirect('/')
```

My template is really basic (I like this simplicity):

```
<p>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</p>
```

Now this approach kind of weirds me out because I am sending the entire rendered HTML page through the session from the `post()` to the `get()`.  But I can't send the `form` with the errors in place through the session back to the the `get()` (that would be prettier) because it won't serialize - you get "Object of type 'BasicForm' is not JSON serializable".

I have done this a different way where I extract the errors form the `form` object into a `list` and then pass my own list of errors from the `post()` to the redirected `get()` and then alter `form.html` to display errors.

```
{% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
    <p style="color:red">Error in {{ error.label }}: {{ error.message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I have not included all the Python code to make this work - but you get the idea. 
 This feels more elegant because I am not putting a blob of HTML into the session, but then the errors display in a way other than the normal Django forms way.  And if I were using crispy forms - then all that crispy UI goodness would not come into play.

I even thought about pulling out the errors in the `post()` code and passing them to the `get()` through the session and then inserting them into the `form` object in the `get()` prior to `render()` - that would feel more elegant too.  If I get bored I might try to dig through the forms structure and implement this as well.

I just cannot believe that with Django having so mush awesome built-in magic - that I can't just say something like `return form.post_redirect_get()`  in the `not form.is_valid` code.

I want something that is a replicable pattern that is easily explained and used the Django UI elements as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding. You're only supposed to redirect after a *successful* post. On a post that fails validation, you don't redirect at all, you redisplay the invalid form - whichwill show the validation errors.

```
form = BasicForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid() 
    return redirect ("/")
else:
    ctx = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, "template.htnl,", ctx)
```

Note, a FormView will handle all this for you; you shouldn't have to define `post` or `get` methods at all.

Comment: That is exactly what I tend to find in all the Django examples and the built in views don't redirect - but it is pretty accepted on the web as the way to make pages so browsers don't freak out when the user refreshes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get - It is like Django didn't get the memo :)

Comment: Again, you've completely misunderstood. Django certainly got the memo, and redirecting *after a successful post* is absolutely recommended everywhere in Django - it's even built in to FormViews. But not after an unsuccessful post, that would be pointless. And note, as your link explains, the point of PRG is to avoid a refresh creating a duplicate resource. If the post is *invalid*, that is impossible, so there is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: I am starting to get the picture.   I have always tried to avoid the dreaded "do you want to report" when the user hits a refresh after a POST that fails validation.  In a sense this is one of the more likely times a user will hit refresh while they are navigating.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok but what happens when you have multiple forms on same page and you want to handle them with different views? Only one `FormView` will handle page rendering and other views will have to redirect to "main view" in both valid and invalid cases.